# Matching column values by row to the difference in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset for a game called League of Legends. Currently the format of the dataset is denoted by participant 0 to 9 (p0-p9) with the role and their gold at 10 minutes into the game as different variables. P0 to p4 are from team 1 and p5 to p9 are from team 2. My goal is to match the two players with the same role and get the difference of their gold.

I tried transposing the dataset long but I can't seem to figure it out. Are there any other methods to solve this?

Editing to show dput, to make it easier to follow the problem.

| p0_gold10 | p0_role | p5_gold10 | p5_role | p1_gold10 | p1_role | p3_gold10 | p3_role | p2_gold | p2_role | p4_gold10 | p4_role | p7_gold10 | p7_role | p9_gold10 | p9_role | p6_gold10 | p6_role | p8_gold10 | p8_role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3334 | JUNGLE | 2804 | DUO_CARRY | 3043 | MIDDLE | 3420 | SOLO | 3142 | MIDDLE | 2455 | TOP | 2899 | DUO_SUPPORT | 2508 | MIDDLE | 3515 | JUNGLE | 2013 | MIDDLE |
| 3648 | JUNGLE | 3175 | TOP | 4042 | MIDDLE | 2380 | DUO_CARRY | 3209 | DUO_SUPPORT | 2784 | TOP | 2930 | MIDDLE | 3669 | JUNGLE | 3271 | DUO_SUPPORT | 4285 | DUO_CARRY |
| 2714 | MIDDLE | 3629 | TOP | 3269 | JUNGLE | 3001 | TOP | 3791 | DUO_SUPPORT | 3142 | DUO_CARRY | 2843 | MIDDLE | 4389 | DUO_SUPPORT | 3359 | DUO_CARRY | 2766 | JUNGLE |
| 3563 | MIDDLE | 2825 | JUNGLE | 3181 | JUNGLE | 3404 | DUO_SUPPORT | 3038 | DUO_CARRY | 2464 | TOP | 4260 | MIDDLE | 3293 | DUO_SUPPORT | 3904 | TOP | 2784 | DUO_CARRY |
| 3402 | DUO_SUPPORT | 3007 | DUO_CARRY | 2074 | MIDDLE | 3208 | TOP | 3246 | JUNGLE | 3076 | DUO_CARRY | 3456 | DUO_SUPPORT | 3607 | JUNGLE | 3477 | JUNGLE | 2086 | MIDDLE |
| 3042 | JUNGLE | 2546 | DUO_SUPPORT | 3885 | DUO_CARRY | 3586 | TOP | 3407 | MIDDLE | 4225 | UO_SUPPORT | 2559 | JUNGLE | 2947 | DUO_CARRY | 2434 | TOP | 3732 | MIDDLE |

As for the end goal of what I'm looking for, I want to categorize the player's gold value by their role and team:

| T1_JUNGLE | T1_MID | T1_DUO_CARRY | T1_SUPPORT | T1_TOP | T2_JUNGLE | T2_MID | T2_DUO_CARRY | T2_SUPPORT | T1_TOP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3334 | 2804 | 3043 | 3420 | 2455 | 2899 | 3142 | 2508 | 3515 | 2013 |
| 3648 | 3175 | 4042 | 2380 | 2784 | 2930 | 3209 | 3669 | 3271 | 4285 |
| 2714 | 3629 | 3269 | 3001 | 3142 | 2843 | 3791 | 4389 | 3359 | 2766 |
| 3563 | 2825 | 3181 | 3404 | 2464 | 4260 | 3038 | 3293 | 3904 | 2784 |
| 3402 | 3007 | 2074 | 3208 | 3076 | 3456 | 3246 | 3607 | 3477 | 2086 |
| 3042 | 2546 | 3885 | 3586 | 4225 | 2559 | 3407 | 2947 | 2434 | 3732 |

```
structure(list(matchId = structure(c(1.86966300926222e-314, 1.8695626867625e-314, 
                                     1.86930711450896e-314, 1.86899691638135e-314, 1.86874315784279e-314, 
                                     1.86873761096778e-314), class = "integer64"), p0_role = c("JUNGLE", 
                                                                                               "JUNGLE", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "DUO_SUPPORT", "JUNGLE"), p0_gold10 = structure(c(1.64721486323472e-320, 
                                                                                                                                                                               1.80235147602887e-320, 1.34089416281314e-320, 1.76035589613236e-320, 
                                                                                                                                                                               1.68081132715192e-320, 1.50294769464907e-320), class = "integer64"), 
               p1_role = c("MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "JUNGLE", "JUNGLE", "MIDDLE", 
                           "DUO_CARRY"), p1_gold10 = structure(c(1.50344176029491e-320, 
                                                                 1.99701334049032e-320, 1.61510059625503e-320, 1.57162281942101e-320, 
                                                                 1.02469214947475e-320, 1.91944503409324e-320), class = "integer64"), 
               p2_role = c("MIDDLE", "DUO_SUPPORT", "DUO_SUPPORT", "DUO_CARRY", 
                           "JUNGLE", "MIDDLE"), p2_gold10 = structure(c(1.5523542592332e-320, 
                                                                        1.58545665750456e-320, 1.87300286338417e-320, 1.50097143206571e-320, 
                                                                        1.60373708640069e-320, 1.68328165538113e-320), class = "integer64"), 
               p3_role = c("SOLO", "DUO_CARRY", "TOP", "DUO_SUPPORT", "TOP", 
                           "TOP"), p3_gold10 = structure(c(1.68970450877706e-320, 1.17587623710217e-320, 
                                                           1.48269100316958e-320, 1.6817994584436e-320, 1.58496259185872e-320, 
                                                           1.77171940598671e-320), class = "integer64"), p4_role = c("TOP", 
                                                                                                                     "TOP", "DUO_CARRY", "TOP", "DUO_CARRY", "DUO_SUPPORT"), p4_gold10 = structure(c(1.21293116054026e-320, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     1.37547875802203e-320, 1.5523542592332e-320, 1.21737775135283e-320, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     1.51974592660767e-320, 2.08742735367927e-320), class = "integer64"), 
               p5_role = c("DUO_CARRY", "TOP", "TOP", "JUNGLE", "DUO_CARRY", 
                           "DUO_SUPPORT"), p5_gold10 = structure(c(1.38536007093886e-320, 
                                                                   1.56865842554596e-320, 1.79296422875788e-320, 1.39573544950152e-320, 
                                                                   1.48565539704463e-320, 1.25789113431181e-320), class = "integer64"), 
               p6_role = c("JUNGLE", "DUO_SUPPORT", "DUO_CARRY", "TOP", 
                           "JUNGLE", "TOP"), p6_gold10 = structure(c(1.73664074513198e-320, 
                                                                     1.61608872754672e-320, 1.65956650438075e-320, 1.92883228136423e-320, 
                                                                     1.71786625059001e-320, 1.20255578197759e-320), class = "integer64"), 
               p7_role = c("DUO_SUPPORT", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE", 
                           "DUO_SUPPORT", "JUNGLE"), p7_gold10 = structure(c(1.43229630729377e-320, 
                                                                             1.44761234231485e-320, 1.40462863112666e-320, 2.10471965128371e-320, 
                                                                             1.70749087202735e-320, 1.26431398770775e-320), class = "integer64"), 
               p8_role = c("MIDDLE", "DUO_CARRY", "JUNGLE", "DUO_CARRY", 
                           "MIDDLE", "MIDDLE"), p8_gold10 = structure(c(9.94554145078429e-321, 
                                                                        2.11707129242974e-320, 1.36658557639689e-320, 1.37547875802203e-320, 
                                                                        1.03062093722484e-320, 1.84385299027953e-320), class = "integer64"), 
               p9_role = c("MIDDLE", "JUNGLE", "DUO_SUPPORT", "DUO_SUPPORT", 
                           "JUNGLE", "DUO_CARRY"), p9_gold10 = structure(c(1.23911663976985e-320, 
                                                                           1.81272685459153e-320, 2.16845411959723e-320, 1.62695817175522e-320, 
                                                                           1.78209478454938e-320, 1.45601145829415e-320), class = "integer64")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                               6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: 1. It would be helpful if you add data in a reproducible format using `dput` so we can copy it. 2. Can you also show your expected output for the data?

Comment: Thanks for including the code! Can you please also include the sample desired output?

Comment: Edited once again, included match Ids to make transposing easier and added expected output.

Comment: How did you get the T1_MIDDLE value of 2804 in the first row of the output? Looking at the input, that looks like the gold for player 5 (which is team 2 in your description) for the role of DUO_CARRY.

Comment: Sorry the output values aren't accurate, I just had them in as filler. I just wanted to show the general format of the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game have two players with same roles in one match so it would be a challenge to get your expected results

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_revised <- df %>%
  select(matchId, contains("role")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("role"), names_to = "player", values_to = "role") %>%
  mutate(player = gsub("_role", "", player)) %>%
  left_join(
    df %>%
      select(matchId, contains("gold")) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = contains("gold"), names_to = "player", values_to = "gold") %>%
      mutate(player = gsub("_gold10", "", player)),
    by = c("matchId", "player")
  ) %>%
  mutate(team = case_when(
    grepl("[0-4]", player) ~ "T1",
    TRUE ~ "T2")) %>%
  mutate(role_markup = paste0(team, "_", role)) %>%
```

This result an df with propler player code, role, team, gold, matchId

```
# A tibble: 60 x 6
      matchId player role           gold team  role_markup   
      <int64> <chr>  <chr>       <int64> <chr> <chr>         
 1 3784240060 p0     JUNGLE         3334 T1    T1_JUNGLE     
 2 3784240060 p1     MIDDLE         3043 T1    T1_MIDDLE     
 3 3784240060 p2     MIDDLE         3142 T1    T1_MIDDLE     
 4 3784240060 p3     SOLO           3420 T1    T1_SOLO       
 5 3784240060 p4     TOP            2455 T1    T1_TOP        
 6 3784240060 p5     DUO_CARRY      2804 T2    T2_DUO_CARRY  
 7 3784240060 p6     JUNGLE         3515 T2    T2_JUNGLE     
 8 3784240060 p7     DUO_SUPPORT    2899 T2    T2_DUO_SUPPORT
 9 3784240060 p8     MIDDLE         2013 T2    T2_MIDDLE     
10 3784240060 p9     MIDDLE         2508 T2    T2_MIDDLE     
# … with 50 more rows
```

You can see that for the first match here, both T1 & T2 has two player with `MIDDLE` role which would result a list if try to pivot wider as below

```
df_revised %>%
  select(matchId, role_markup, gold) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "role_markup", values_from = "gold")
```

This output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 7
   role_markup    `3784240060` `3784037005` `3783519721` `3782891873` `3782378260` `3782367033`
   <chr>          <list>       <list>       <list>       <list>       <list>       <list>      
 1 T1_JUNGLE      <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]> 
 2 T1_MIDDLE      <int64 [2]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]> 
 3 T1_SOLO        <int64 [1]>  <NULL>       <NULL>       <NULL>       <NULL>       <NULL>      
 4 T1_TOP         <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]> 
 5 T2_DUO_CARRY   <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]> 
 6 T2_JUNGLE      <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [2]>  <int64 [1]> 
 7 T2_DUO_SUPPORT <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]> 
 8 T2_MIDDLE      <int64 [2]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]> 
 9 T1_DUO_SUPPORT <NULL>       <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]> 
10 T1_DUO_CARRY   <NULL>       <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]> 
11 T2_TOP         <NULL>       <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <int64 [1]>  <NULL>       <int64 [1]> 
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

If the goal is to compare acrossing match then I can just take average or sum of gold for each match.

```
df_revised %>%
  select(matchId, role_markup, gold) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "role_markup", values_from = "gold", values_fn = {sum})
```

Which output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 7
   role_markup    `3784240060` `3784037005` `3783519721` `3782891873` `3782378260` `3782367033`
   <chr>               <int64>      <int64>      <int64>      <int64>      <int64>      <int64>
 1 T1_JUNGLE              3334         3648         3269         3181         3246         3042
 2 T1_MIDDLE              6185         4042         2714         3563         2074         3407
 3 T1_SOLO                3420           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
 4 T1_TOP                 2455         2784         3001         2464         3208         3586
 5 T2_DUO_CARRY           2804         4285         3359         2784         3007         2947
 6 T2_JUNGLE              3515         3669         2766         2825         7084         2559
 7 T2_DUO_SUPPORT         2899         3271         4389         3293         3456         2546
 8 T2_MIDDLE              4521         2930         2843         4260         2086         3732
 9 T1_DUO_SUPPORT           NA         3209         3791         3404         3402         4225
10 T1_DUO_CARRY             NA         2380         3142         3038         3076         3885
11 T2_TOP                   NA         3175         3629         3904           NA         2434
```

And with this we can output the format you wanted

```
df_revised %>%
  select(matchId, role_markup, gold) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "role_markup", values_from = "gold", values_fn = {sum})
```

Final output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 12
     matchId T1_JUNGLE T1_MIDDLE T1_SOLO  T1_TOP T2_DUO_CARRY T2_JUNGLE T2_DUO_SUPPORT T2_MIDDLE T1_DUO_SUPPORT T1_DUO_CARRY  T2_TOP
     <int64>   <int64>   <int64> <int64> <int64>      <int64>   <int64>        <int64>   <int64>        <int64>      <int64> <int64>
1 3784240060      3334      6185    3420    2455         2804      3515           2899      4521             NA           NA      NA
2 3784037005      3648      4042      NA    2784         4285      3669           3271      2930           3209         2380    3175
3 3783519721      3269      2714      NA    3001         3359      2766           4389      2843           3791         3142    3629
4 3782891873      3181      3563      NA    2464         2784      2825           3293      4260           3404         3038    3904
5 3782378260      3246      2074      NA    3208         3007      7084           3456      2086           3402         3076      NA
6 3782367033      3042      3407      NA    3586         2947      2559           2546      3732           4225         3885    2434
```

Comment: Hm, I didn't realize but my data is just wrong. Thanks for the solution though since it is what I wanted.